# base64 or physical image in folder

Tags: php, mysql, base64

I have a problem with a table where I store images and these I have in base64, but growing up the table this was very slow.

It is advisable to store the images in a folder? or field which stores the image in base64 must have a special feature?

I can recommend?

Comment: do you mean a database table? Isn't a good solution store files in databases, better in folders (thought for files)

Comment: I have a table in mysql which contains a BLOB field that contains the images in base64, my question is whether it is advisable to do this? or just decode the image on the server and save the image to a folder physics?

thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never use your database to carry images because as much as images quantity increases slower the database.
You can achieve this by uploading the image in a separate folder and storing only the name of the image in `database`

**AT FRONT END**

You can get them by giving the path `images/$imageVariable`

Comment: Thanks ..... wanted to know about this

Comment: This has been answered earlier. Please just leave a link to the existing answer per a comment.